# Is it possible to search for keys within an object within a field within a document in mongoDB?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a form on a page, I want a user to enter something in the form click submit, then make a request to MongoDB using the input of that form and render parts of that request onto a page, using nodejs, mongoose, and ejs

The schema of the collection has a field that always contains an object and I would like to search for a document in the collection that has a key that matches the input of the form.

The schema of the collection is

```
const ArrivalTimesSchema = new mongoose.Schema({

 postcodeArrivalTimes: {
   type: Object,
   required: true,
  },
 workerId: {
   type: String,
   required: false
  },
 company: {
   type: String,
   required: true    
  },
})
```

And an example of postcodeArrivalTimes is

```
postcodeArrivalTimes = {AL95AT:"07:06", DL56EP:"13:06",AL14PL:"19:15"}
```

So in this case if someone input AL95AT into the input form I would want this document returned, how would I do that?

Not all documents would contain the key AL95AT but there could be multiple and I would like the last.

For this I think I can use .sort({ $natural: -1 }).limit(1) within a find() but I am not sure how to search for the keys within the object within the field.

Thank you for any help!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
let input = "input" //inputKeyValue
let query = {};
query[input] = { $exists: true };
db.collection.find(query).sort({ $natural: -1 }).limit(1)
```